# Newest price for an item in LINQ / LAMBDA

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

How do I formulate the following in LINQ with LAMBDA expressions.

Given (for simplicity - this is actually later a join) a table with the fields:

- Item
- Price
- Timestamp

which is mapped to a class. I use BlToolkit, but could also be LINQ or EF - makes no difference.

I want the object with Item = 2 and the highest timestamp (newest) and / or a query of ALL items but ONLY the most current object.

How do I formulate this?

I understand there will likely be a subselect involved, but I have a problem finding the correct syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using fluent syntax, the item with the highest timestamp, and `Item==2` is:

```
var item= table.Where(i => i.Item == 2)
               .OrderByDescending(i => i.Timestamp)
               .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Should be using OrderByDescending.

Comment: Ok, and how do I do that when I want a LIST of items? Or ALL items? Top item of everythinw where the name includes "processor"?